# How to stop my snow code from happening on other scenes

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am working on Actionscript 3 code on my AIR app, in one off the middle scenes. When I swipe to another scene, the snow refreshes and carries on falling. What code should I put in the scenes before and after the scene with the snow code shown below, to stop the snow code from happening again?

```
"stop();  

//Snow Flake Animation start

var snowarr = new Array();

var maxflakes:int = 60;

for(var s:int = 0; s<maxflakes; s++)
{
    var sf:snowflake = new snowflake();
    addChild(sf as DisplayObject);
    sf.x = Math.random()*stage.stageWidth;
    sf.y = 0-Math.random()*stage.stageWidth;
    var snowsize:Number = .3+(Math.random()*.6);
    sf.scaleX = sf.scaleY = sf.snowsize = snowsize;
    snowarr.push(sf);
    sf.cacheAsBitmap = true;
}

for(s = 0; s<maxflakes; s++)
{
    sf = new snowflake();
    addChild(sf as DisplayObject);
    sf.x = Math.random()*stage.stageWidth;
    sf.y = 0-Math.random()*stage.stageWidth;
    snowsize = .9+(Math.random()*.6);
    sf.scaleX = sf.scaleY = sf.snowsize = snowsize;
    snowarr.push(sf);
    sf.cacheAsBitmap = true;
}

function updateFlakes(event:Event):void
{
    for(var f:int = 0; f<(maxflakes*2); f++)
    {
        snowarr[f].y+=snowarr[f].snowsize*4;
        if(snowarr[f].y>stage.stageHeight)
        {
            snowarr[f].y-=stage.stageHeight;
        }
    }
}

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateFlakes);
//Snow flake Animation End"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function set showSnow(b:boolean):void{
      if (b) {
              addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateFlakes);
      }else{
              removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateFlakes);
              /* add some routines to remove any flakes currently on the stage */
      }
    }



Now, when you change pages, call this function to turn the snow on and off.
```

take care,
lee

Comment: Hi lee, I actually no very little code, as this code was copied from some where else on-line. How exactly do i use your code here. When copied in, i get an error saying "Pic_32, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1415, Line 44 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: boolean." I do apologize for for being useless. No worries if its to much to ask.

Comment: Probably needs to be Boolean, not boolean. I guess I assumed you wrote the original code. It would be very difficult to determine the best way to implement this. If you can find some code that handles changing pages, you could make the call to this function from there.